# is it possible to store gsl_matrix in a c++ vector?

Tags: c++, gsl

is it possible to store gsl_matrix in a c++ vector?  Or are there some ways to store a 5*5 `gsl_matrix` as an element of a user defined `struct`? Is `vector<gsl_matrix>`syntex right

Comment: Did you try it? C++ specializes very well in this sort of thing.

Comment: There are a few old bindings (http://gslwrap.sourceforge.net/), but I'd switch to Eigen as its more modern.

Comment: @DeiDei I didn't try cause I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on DeiDei's comment, I tried it and here is an example.

```
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<gsl_matrix> vector_matrix;
    gsl_matrix *a, *c;
    a = gsl_matrix_alloc(2,2);
    c = gsl_matrix_alloc(2,2);
    for(size_t i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(size_t j=0; j<2;j++)
            gsl_matrix_set(a, i, j, i+j);
            gsl_matrix_set(c, i, j, i+j);
    }
    vector_matrix.push_back(*a);
    vector_matrix.push_back(*c);
    vector_matrix.push_back(*a);
    gsl_blas_dgemm(CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,
                   1.0,&vector_matrix[0],&vector_matrix[1],
                   1.0,&vector_matrix[2]);
    for(size_t i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(size_t j=0; j<2;j++)
            cout<<gsl_matrix_get(&vector_matrix[2],i,j)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, does this mean that the vector_matrix[0] and vector_matrix[1] have the same pointer and will always have the same value? I am wondering, if I want to store a vector of 10 gsl_matrix, does that mean I need 10 pointer variables to keep it work?